# No characters on screen sent to an Ncurses pad

Tags: c, ubuntu, ncurses

This should work
Can anyone tell me why I see no typed output on the screen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>


int nRows;
int nCols;

WINDOW  *myPad;


int main(void)
{

  initscr();

  getmaxyx(stdscr, nRows, nCols);

  myPad = newpad(nRows, nCols);


  while (1)
  {
    waddch(myPad, wgetch(myPad));
    prefresh(myPad, 0, 0, 0, 0, nRows, nCols);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have no idea ... other similar examples work.
Could this be an Ubuntu issue?

18.04.3 latest patches of today.

Comment: nRows and nCols are being used before they are assigned a value

Comment: @jmq technically they are declared globally, so they are zero-initialized automatically so they are actually assigned before use. But yes, that is probably also problematic

Comment: Sorry ... typo on my part. I changed getyx() to getmaxyx() ... still no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `initscr`, the current position in `stdscr` is **`0,0`**.  Your program then asks for the position and uses it as the size of a pad:

> [getyx(stdscr, nRows, nCols);](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getyx.3x.html)
>
> [myPad = newpad(nRows, nCols);](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_pad.3x.html#h3-newpad)

A *pad* with **zero** lines and **zero** columns will not show much on the screen.

In the altered question, there are still two problems:

- the input is buffered (use `cbreak` to change that)
- there is a missing `refresh` before the loop (to ensure that `stdscr` is displayed).

Here is a diff showing what might be done to fix those problems:

```
> diff -u foo.c.orig foo.c
--- foo.c.orig  2019-08-21 19:24:24.000000000 -0400
+++ foo.c       2019-08-21 19:30:46.202769968 -0400
@@ -13,12 +13,14 @@
 {
 
   initscr();
+  cbreak();
+  noecho();
 
   getmaxyx(stdscr, nRows, nCols);
 
   myPad = newpad(nRows, nCols);
 
-
+  refresh();
   while (1)
   {
     waddch(myPad, wgetch(myPad));
```

Comment: Sorry ... typo on my part. I changed getyx() to getmaxyx() ... still no output.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Thomas ... but I was under the impression that I did not need to referesh() since STDSCR is no used?

Comment: Don't ask me why ... but today ... the code I originally posted (with the getmaxyx() correction) works. I fixed the typo yesterday and it did not. Problem now is that if I change x and y here ... getmaxyx(win, 0, 0, y, x, nRows, nCols) ... I get no output again.

Comment: each time I make a change ... and recompile ... I seem to be getting intermittent no output with correct output ... not sure why ... but the original question was answered by all three posters ... so thanks all !